# Can't adjust label widths. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such a sketch: http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/upcZJ/.

I found an article http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/07/09/Justify-elements-using-jQuery-and-CSS.aspx which explains how to adjust label widths relative to the widest one.

But I can't do the same. What have I missed? I've tried do the thing inside an `accordion tab` and inside `aside division`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your label elements are `display: inline` (the default) so the `width` property does not apply.

Set `display` to something else (e.g. `inline-block`)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the CSS which was mentioned in the article

```
label, input[type="text"]{
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
label
{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.field{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:5px 0px;
}
```